# How can I update multiple state variables using setState while using the spread operator?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

In my component, state looks like this:

```
this.state = {
            userAnswers:{},
            numAnswered:0
        }
```

I have a method which when invoked, should add or re-set a key-value pair in `userAnswers`, and it should also increment numAnswered by 1

This code works:

```
 handleUserAnswer = (questionId, answer) => {

    
        this.setState(prevState => ({
         
          userAnswers: {
              ...prevState.userAnswers,
              [questionId]:answer
          }

        
      }),() => console.log(this.state))

      this.setState(prevState =>({
      numAnswered:prevState.numAnswered+1

     }), ()=> console.log(this.state))

    }
```

But how can I achieve this without having to use setState twice? For eg, why does the following not work?

```
 handleUserAnswer = (questionId, answer) => {

    
        this.setState(prevState => ({
         
          userAnswers: {
              ...prevState.userAnswers,
              [questionId]:answer,
              numAnswered:prevState.numAnswered+1

          }

        
      }),() => console.log(this.state))

    }
```

The value of numAnswered is not being incremented here..

Comment: In the second code example you got the structure of your state object wrong. Therefore its not working as expected.

Comment: "..you got the structure of your state object wrong". Could you please elaborate on what you mean by this? I cannot spot the mistake here

Comment: You want your state object to look like this `{ userAnswers: { someID: someAnswer }, numAnswered: 0 }` but in your second code snippet where you try to have only one single setState call you end up creating this `{ userAnswers: { someID: someAnswer, numAnswered: 0 } }` instead.

Comment: I see what you mean now @Martin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second case, you are updating numAnswered inside userAnswers instead of directly inside the state. Try this:

```
handleUserAnswer = (questionId, answer) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({  
        userAnswers: {
            ...prevState.userAnswers,
            [questionId]: answer,
        }.
        numAnswered:prevState.numAnswered + 1
    }), () => console.log(this.state))
}
```